# Best Place to Put "Auto Start" another activity code?

Tags: android

My Android application(Application A) launches another application (say Application B) **upon click of a button**.

Now I want to implement "auto start" functionality wherein Application B will be launched as soon as Application A is launched. 
For this, I created a checkbox and used `SharedPreferences` to store the value of checkbox. 
Then, in my `onCreate()` method of Activity A, I am checking the value of checkbox from `SharedPreferences` and launching Application B in case the value is "true".

**The Problem:**

The problem I am facing is, when the user exits "Application B" (and comes back to Application A) the `onCreate()` of Application A is getting called again and Application B opens up again. This sets off a infinite loop and at exit of Application B, user returns to Application A and goes to Application B again.

I know onCreate() gets called multiple times (when we change orientation, keyboard opened, Activity goes into background and is killed by system), but is there any clean way of doing this?

To reiterate, my requirement is to launch Application B from Application A if the "auto start" checkbox is checked in Application A.

Comment: unless you are calling finish on Application A, it shouldn't call onCreate again and should only call onPause, can you please share some code :)

Comment: show some code, and part of you `Manifest` file

Comment: Two different applications? Did you mean two different Android activities instead? It sounds to me like you're trying to construct a EULA for your application. If that's the case, even having two different activities might be overkill. See:  http://www.donnfelker.com/android-a-simple-eula-for-your-android-apps/

Comment: Also hopefully, you won't be using the term "auto start" next to a checkbox in your application. When I think of an application auto-starting, I think of an application auto-restarting every time the parent device it's installed upon boots up.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: They are not two different activities but two different applications. Think of it as giving a "Launch Gmail" link(a button). Some custom logic is executed and then other application is launched when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion will be to use the method `onPause` of the activity in application A and set a flag there "application B was called". Then if this flag is set do not call application B in `onCreate` of the activity in Application A and unset the flag.

If application B is too long in the foreground application A might be suspended by the system and the flag will be reset. In such case maybe it is good idea to have the flag stored in some persistent storage (e.g. `SharedPreferences`).

**EDIT** One more thing: the flag should be set in `onPause` only if the activity is being paused, because the other application will be shown (this will be easily determinable, because everything happens in the same class).

Comment: When should the flag be "cleared" in normal course of action?

Comment: @Manish The flag is cleared in `onCreate` of the activity in application A, immediately after you check whether it has already been set. I have edited my answer a bit BTW.

Comment: and why not to simply check onCreate's Bundle parameter, simple as it should be

Comment: @pskink what will you get out of that? you are assuming that nothing else happens in application A, but starting application B. This is obviously not so, as there is at least second activity: the setting activity.

Comment: if a Bundle is null it means it is a fresh start, if not null it means that activity is recreated due low memory, orientation change etc